# Toggle switch не виден

Tags: java, android

[image: рабочее приложение]

написал простое приложение на Samsung sm-t311, а switch toggle виджет не виден. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема

Отрывок из активити-класса

```
        Switch toggle = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    toggle.setTextOn("On");
    toggle.setTextOff("Off");
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
    });
```

Вся разметка :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:id="@+id/myLabel"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="New Switch"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_weight="0.14"
    android:clickable="true"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если один из предложенных ответов решил вашу проблему, то вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить "верным".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас высота элемента равна нулю

> android:layout_height="0dp"

засим и не виден.

**UPD_0**

1) Создал с нуля пустой проект.

2) Убрал из вашей разметки строки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

android:weightSum="1"

android:layout_weight="0.14"
```

3) Запустил и получил:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: сделал `android:layout_height="50dp"` , андройд студия предложила вернуть 0 для улучшения производительности(что за жесть). Свитча по прежнему не видно

Comment: Ну... Приведите весь код разметки, что ли...

Comment: И проверьте нужна ли вам строчка **android:layout_weight="0.08"** с таким странным значение веса. Именно из-за веса студия и предлагает обнулить высоту.

Comment: похоже, это мое устройство как-то криво отображает все. Потому, что эмулируемое устройство отображает все нормально

Comment: Меня всё же сильно смущает наличие у вас строк **android:layout_weight="0.14"** и **android:weightSum="1"**. Они точно вам нужны?..

Comment: Убрал их. Все равно не видно свитча(

Comment: См. обновление ответа.

Comment: Щас винда обновится до 10, и проверю. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А кстати, оффтоп, что лучше читать по деву на андройде, с Java se,ee работаю давно